# Retrofit Custom callback and unchecked assignments

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to create my own retrofit callback handler because I want to hide a loading screen once the call is done and would rather not repeat the call. I'm getting a Unchecked Assignment warning when using my custom RetrofitCallback and not retrofit2.Callback. What is the correct way to fix this warning?

```
public abstract class RetrofitCallback<T> implements Callback {
    private BaseActivity mContext;

    public RetrofitCallback(Context context) {
        mContext = (BaseActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
        mContext.hideLoading();
        onSuccess(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
        mContext.hideLoading();
    }

    public abstract void onSuccess(@NonNull Response<T> response);
}
```

Call being made

```
service.getSignupCode(request).enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<SignupResponse>(this) {        
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Response<SignupResponse> response) {

    }
});
```

Comment: would be helpful if you add the warnings as well here

Comment: It's what I said in the original post. "Unchecked Assignment: 'anonymous com.packagename.network.RetrofitCallback<SignupResponse>' to 'retrofit2.Callback<SignupResponse>'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this below code?. The one mistake I can figure out is implementing `Callback` instead of `Callback<T>`

```
public abstract class RetrofitCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {
private BaseActivity mContext;

public RetrofitCallback(Context context) {
    mContext = (BaseActivity) context;
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
    mContext.hideLoading();
    onSuccess(response);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
    mContext.hideLoading();
}

public abstract void onSuccess(@NonNull Response<T> response);
```

}

Comment: That is perfect and I feel kind of silly now. I was making everything else generic including my context. Thank you.